# How to construct such sequence

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, differential-operators

Consider the operator  $T=i(x\partial_y -y\partial_x)$ with $i^2=-1$, [ or  in polar coordinates $T=i\partial_{\theta},\quad (x,y)\to (r,\theta)$].

My question is, I want to construct a sequence $(u_n)$

$u_n\to 0$ weakly.

$\forall n\in \Bbb{N}:||u_n||=1$.

$||T u_n||\to 0$

were $||f||^2=\int_{\Bbb{R}^2} f(x,y)\overline{f(x,y)} dxdy $.

Note that for a radial function $f$ we have $T(f)=0$.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding you, but could you take a radial function and translate it to $\infty$? Then you would expect weak convergence to $0$ similar to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2163611/how-translation-generates-weak-convergence).

Comment: @ Keith McClary,  It  works. Thanks